# What causes high latency of parallel SQS delivery?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs

Using the Node SDK, I am seeing high latency of about 9000 ms to deliver SQS messages when messages are sent in parallel on multiple queues.  If I sent all the messages sequentially on one queue, I get much lower latency of about 300 ms.  In both tests, messages are sent in batches of 10 using the code below.  The send timestamp is put inside the message itself, so I can measure the delivery time when the message gets received.

**Why is it so much slower to transfer messages sent in parallel queues?**  Does Amazon do rate limiting?

[image]

[image]

```
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var entry = {
          Id: String(messageCount),
          MessageBody: "test"+messageCount+(new Date().getTime()),
          MessageDeduplicationId: "test"+messagecount+" "+(new Date().getTime())
        };
        entries.push(entry);
        messageCount += 1;
      }
      var params = {
        QueueUrl: queueUrls[senderIndex],
        Entries: entries
      };
      sqs.sendMessageBatch(params, function(batchSendErr, results) {
              ...
      });
```

In the sequential case, I run one node program that sends 500 batches of 10 messages on a single queue, and one program that receives 500 batches of 10 messages.  (500 messages total.)

In the parallel case, I run one node program that creates 250 writer threads and sends two batches of 10 messages from each to one of 250 different queues.  I run another node program that created 250 reader threads and receives two batches of 10 messages from each. (5000 messages total)

For the tests above, I use FIFO queues, although results are similar with non-FIFO queues.

I do notice that in the parallel send case, each batch send call to the AWS SDK takes about 5 seconds to get a completion callback.  In the sequential case, each batch send call to the AWS SDK takes about 300ms.  I'm not sure why the API calls are slower in parallel unless AWS is rate limiting my calls.

BTW, here is what my queue setup looks like.  There are 250 of these queues with #{item} ranging from 1 to 250

`aws sqs create-queue --queue-name loadtest_device#{item}_user#{item}.fifo --attributes "FifoQueue=true,VisibilityTimeout=300,ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds=0"`

Comment: Please make sure your "250 writer threads" are run parallel. I mean you should print out started time of all threads.

Comment: Fair point, @TuanVA.  I am confident they are sent in parallel. The sequential send case took 61.199 secs to send 5000 messages (time to last sendMessageBatch callback)  peaking at 1 open socket, and the parallel send case took 11.607 secs to send them all, peaking at 249 open sockets.  I count sockets by incrementing a counter right before the sendMessageBatch call, and decrementing it in the callback.

Comment: This is most definitely going to be a flaw in your test methodology that needs to be identified, not a limit in SQS... and your "socket counting" strategy is suspect, since you didn't mention accounting for this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-maxsockets.html

Comment: Good tip, @Michael-sqlbot.  Indeed, I did not know about that socket setting.  I tried to quickly insert code to set the max to 500, and re-ran tests, but saw no difference.  That said, I can try to use an OS tool to measure open sockets and perhaps see if this is still limited for some reason.   `var https = require('https'); var agent = new https.Agent({ maxSockets: 500 });  AWS.config.update({ httpOptions:{ agent: agent } });`  Also, if I simply drop the number of parallel senders/receivers from 250 to 25, the mean latency goes down from 8000ms to 2000ms but it does not drop to 300ms.

Comment: With so many connections, you are almost certainly spending a lot of CPU cycles negotiating TLS, and I'd look there, next. Something local is blocking.

Comment: I used this command to count open sockets `lsof -i 4tcp:443`, and indeed, the "Node" process has 250 sockets in the established state. So I don't think the number of sockets is limiting.  The top command says the  CPU does go  to 100% during the parallel send operation.  (And it goes to 43% during the sequential send).  It only takes 4 parallel sends to bring the CPU to 100%, so indeed it is surprisingly (to me) CPU intensive to send messages.

Comment: Even if I run only four senders in parallel (keeping the CPU at about 99%) the receive latency is still almost 2000ms vs. 300ms for  a single sender.  So there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this issue with an Amazon support engineer, he showed that he could not reproduce the results.  His theory was that the latency problem was caused by a network bottleneck, particularly WiFi traffic congestion as both test networks were using the same WiFi radio space.

I was never fully able to confirm as I did not have access to two independent wired network connections.  I did witness that SQS send operations have a large and verbose data payload and do use significantly higher bandwidth than other operations (2x data overhead size vs lambda calls.)  This is consistent with the network bottleneck theory.